# Capitalize first letter in each sentence in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to capitalize the first letter in each sentence, however there are some HTML tags embedded in the string like below.

`this is my dog. <font color="red">he</font> is very nice. he likes to <b>play</b>. <b>he</b> likes to growl.`

How can I ensure that every first letter of each sentence, excluding the HTML tags, are capitalized but still keep the tags? Desired output:

`This is my dog. <font color="red">He</font> is very nice. He likes to <b>play</b>. <b>He</b> likes to growl.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression aren't my strongest but I believe something like this would work.

```py
import re

def capitalize(input):
    result = []
    
    sentences = re.findall('([\w<][^\.!?]*[\.!?])',input)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if sentence[0] != '<':
            sentence = sentence.capitalize()
        else:
            tag_text = re.findall('>(.*?)<', sentence)
            first_tag = '>' + tag_text[0].capitalize() + '<'
            sentence = re.sub('>(.*?)<', first_tag, sentence)

        result.append(sentence)

    return ' '.join(result)
```

I believe the that substitution regex could probably be simplified, to not have to insert the '>' & '<' back in.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with ...

```
text = "this is my dog. <font color=\"red\">he</font> is very nice. he likes to <b>play</b>. <b>he</b> likes to growl."
newString = []
upcaseNextLetter = True
skip = False

for letter in text:
    if(not skip):
        skip = letter=="<"
        if(not skip):
            letter = letter.upper() if upcaseNextLetter else letter
            upcaseNextLetter = (letter==" " and upcaseNextLetter) or letter=="."
    else:
        skip = not letter==">"

    newString.append(letter)
    
text = ''.join(newString)
```

I just skip whenever we're between brackets. And I uppercase if we saw a dot or a space following a dot.

Comment: Thank you for your help!